Why is the first line in useEffect ignored
using socket.io and whenever a signal is received from the client and useeffect is invoked the first console log is ignored and only the second one runs
import { socket } from "../socket.js"

useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('effect ran')
        socket.on('turn',(data)=>{
            console.log('the data', data)
        }
},[socket])

i have simplified my code to see if this was all on my end but the first console log is still ignored

Did you somehow clear the console after the component mounted and so now you are only seeing the logs for the "onTurn" event? We may need quite a bit more context here.

No I havent cleared the console, using the debugger and going step by step the first console log is skipped as well @DrewReese

I know you say your code is simplified here, but you do know useEffect does require been placed inside a component?.   And that component getting rendered..

Interesting... and I don't see how that's even possible. Are you sure you are running the latest version/instance of your code? Please [edit] the post to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with. See also if you can create a running Codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.

"whenever a signal is received from the client and useeffect is invoked the first console log is ignored and only the second one runs", but how about when the component mounts? Does everything work like it should? If it does but after that it then behaves like you described then there is nothing wrong with the implementation you are working with. Brian I want you to do this; I want you to monitor the whole program from component mount all the way to Socket.io signals. Can you do that Brian?

It is because the effect is not invoked again after it is invoked the first time. What you are seeing is the invocation of the arrow function registered as the event handler of socket.on event handler property.

The arrow function registered to useEffect() will always be invoked on component mount and then whenever the dependency array of the useEffect() changes so what happens is that on this first invocation, an arrow function is registered as the event handler of socket.on event handler property. Now whenever socket.on::'turn' event is fired, that arrow function is invoked and this arrow function is different from the arrow function registered as the effect of the useEffect().
See code analysis. The keynote is that the arrow function of useEffect() and the arrow function of the event handler property socket.on are different.

useEffect(() => { /* <—— [socket] doesn’t change hence arrow function is only invoked on component mount. */
    console.log('effect ran') /* <—— [socket] doesn’t change hence arrow function is only invoked on component mount, 'effect ran' is only logged once. */
    socket.on('turn', (data) => { /* <—— [socket] doesn’t change hence arrow function is only invoked on component mount and this event handler is registered only once. But it may be invoked multiple times whenever socket.on::'turn' event is fired. */
        console.log('the data', data)
    }
}, [socket]) /* <—— [socket] doesn’t change hence arrow function is only invoked on component mount. */

OP states the first console log is never hit somehow, e.g. it was "ignored". This answer doesn't explain this scenario that OP is asking about.

"whenever a signal is received from the client and useeffect is invoked the first console log is ignored and only the second one runs". The OP thinks the effect runs each time a signal is received from the client. I think you are the one reading it the other way Drew. By the way I’ve always wanted to say this; I’m a huge follower of yours. Anyways back to the discussion, the OP has a misconception of the mechanics of the working code.

No, I think I understood it well enough. See the comments under the post where I asked if they somehow missed the first log, and possibly cleared it, and are now only seeing the event logs, and OP confirmed no, they stepped through the code with a debugger and the first log is "ignored". I don't think that is possible and asked for a [mcve]. I don't disagree that the OP has a misunderstanding somewhere though.
